# Specific game makes my PC Restart?

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, troubleshooting, reboot

So I play couple of games and one of them, named Dota 2 makes my PC Restart. This happens only while playing Dota 2 in around 15 minutes times. Some times PC restarts as soon as the game launches, some times I am able to play for around 15 minutes before the PC restarts.

I stress tested the GPU, CPU, RAM, scanned drives and nothing happens. I even stress tested all the GPU, RAM and CPU all at the same time for 20 minutes and there was no problem.

Here is a log file of the GPU usage, before the PC restarts:

```
Date:                         2019-07-29 01:58:56
GPU Clock [MHz]:              1097.4
Memory Clock [MHz]            1502.3
GPU Temperature [°C]          77.0
Fan Speed (%) [%]             84 
Fan Speed (RPM) [RPM]         2880 
Memory Used [MB]              1379
GPU Load [%]                  99
Memory Controller Load [%]    38
Video Engine Load [%]         0
Bus Interface Load [%]        6
Power Consumption (W) [W]     149.5
Power Consumption (%) [% TDP] 69.9
PerfCap Reason []             4 
VDDC [V]                      1.2000
CPU Temperature [°C]          56.0
System Memory Used [MB]       5011
```

Here are some pictures of the event logs, hope it gives you enough inside of what could be the reason for this game making my PC restarts.
[Windows 10 Event logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAWRL.jpg)

I think the proublem could lay in the DistributedCOM warnings in the logs, that did not gave permission to something. 
Steam uses something called ***Steamworks Common Redistributables*** That are some C++ Libraries and API's for the game, but not sure.

Comment: Could be an issue with the disk it's installed on. Is it on the same disk as Windows? If not, try moving it there. It could be that some asset is being accessed 15 mins into each game but I don't know Dota well enough to guess at what it could be

Answer (score 0):

1. [Check if your system can run Dota 2](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri).
2. Try running [Steam as Administrator](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-how-to-fix-dota-2-crash-issues/).
3. Try autoconfig and/or safe launch options (see above link).